# Prove the given equality with sets of prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

> Let $\mathbb{S}$ be the set of $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ ($x_j\in \mathbb{Z^+}, x_{j+1}>x_j$) which have no prime divisors other than $p_1,p_2,...,p_i$, these primes are also the zeros of a polynomial say $P(x)$. Prove,
> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow∞} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{k=1}^i(1-p_k)\right)=\lim_{n \rightarrow ∞}x_n\cdot(P(-1)+P(0)[2(-1)^i-1])$$

I tried using Euler's function on $x_n$ as the LHS looks quite similar.

$\Phi(x_n)\cdot P(0)=(-1)^i x_n\left(\prod_{k=1}^i(1-p_k)\right)$

But now I don't know how to use $\Phi(x_n)$ can someone help me solving this problem?

Comment: Please state the source of the proposition. Is it a book, a paper or a website?

Comment: Apparently, the proposition in the question is incorrect. For example, let $i=1, p_1=2, x_1=1, x_2=2, \cdots, x_n=2^{n-1}, P(x)=x-2$.  Without $\lim_{n \to\infty}$, LHS $=(2^n-1)(-1)=-2^n+1$, RHS $= 2^{n-1}(-3+(-2)(-3))=2^{n-1}3$. When $n\to\infty$, the ratio of RHS to LHS converges to $-\frac32\not=1$ . Moreover, if we set $P(x)=2(x-2)$, it doubles RHS but leaving LHS intact.